# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ minus a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know that $\mathbb R^3-\text{circle}$ has a fundamental group equal to $\mathbb Z$ and I was wondering if some things could be said about $\mathbb R^n-\text{circle}$ for $n>3$. In particular, I'd like to show that it is simply connected.

Do you know if it is true and how to prove it ?

Thanks !

P.S: I have tried to show that it strong retracts to a simpler space but all my attempts failed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ minus a point is homotopy equivalent to the $(n-1)$-sphere.

Comment: Thanks @KentaS, I know this fact but don’t really know how this will help me.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>3,\;\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^n-S^1)\cong0$ . Intuitively because $n$ is at least 4 ( and 1+1<4) we know that any two loops can be homotoped to be disjoint therefore, nullhomotopic loops will stay null homotopic after removing $S^1.$

$\textbf{Idea:}$ Van-Kampen's theorem can be used to show that the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^n-K\hookrightarrow S^n-K$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1.$ Then it follows from $S^n-S^m\simeq S^{n-m-1}$ if $n-m>2$ the fundamental group remains trivial. (Shown here: [Fundamental group of $S^n \setminus S^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395200/fundamental-group-of-sn-setminus-sm))

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: This answer implicitly assumes that the circle is smoothly embedded in $R^n$. For topological embeddings the claim is false.